# can i overwrite an excel file using php?

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

I created the file using `PHPExcel` at say `C:\path\goes\here\filename.xls` 
When I try to access it using `header(),` it creates a file `filename(1)` , `filename(2)` and so on.
(PS : When i say overwrite, I mean to erase previous content and add new data).

```
<?php

include 'PHPExcel.php';

require_once ("C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\excel_mailer_2\\PHPMailer-master\\class.phpmailer.php");

$path           =   "C:\\Users\\Manish\\Downloads";
$file_name      =   $_GET['file_name'];

$DB_server      =   "localhost";
$DB_username    =   "root";
$DB_password    =   "";
$DB_dbname      =   "timetracker";
$DB_tablename   =   "tt_users";

$conn           =   mysqli_connect ($DB_server, $DB_username, $DB_password, $DB_dbname);

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    die ("Connection Failed!");
}

$sql    =   "SELECT *";
$sql    .=  " FROM $DB_tablename";

if ($result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql));

else die("Couldn't execute query:<br />" . mysqli_error(). "<br />" . mysqli_errno());

$file_ending = ".xls";

$filename = $file_name.$file_ending;

//header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");



/*******Start of Formatting for Excel*******/

$sep        = "\t";
$flag       = true;
$col_names  = "";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $data_insert    = "";
            foreach($row as $field=>$data) {
        if ($flag)
            $col_names      .= $field.$sep;
        if(!isset($data))
            $data_insert    .= "NULL".$sep;
        elseif ($data != "")
            $data_insert    .= $data.$sep;
        else
            $data_insert    .= "".$sep;
    }

    if ($flag) {
        $flag       = !$flag;
        $col_names  .= "\t";
        echo (trim($col_names));
        echo "\n";
    }
    $data_insert    .= "\t";
    echo (trim($data_insert));
    echo "\n";
}
?>
```

Comment: Nothing to do with PHPExcel or with PHP, that's browser behaviour

Comment: @Mark Baker, so you say it's not possible?

Comment: I'm saying that if you send a file to the browser, then it's up to the browser itself, or the client user to determine what name the file will be saved as, and the server side code can only "suggest" a filename

Comment: This is a security measure, otherwise a simple piece of server code could be used by malicious individuals to overwrite system files on the client PC, replacing them with viruses or malware, or simply rendering the PC useless

Answer (score 0):

Hi write your `filename` in `header` function using this

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="filename.xls"');
```

Comment: i did that.. i just edited my question and shared my code

Comment: i sent the desired file name through `$file_name` from `index.php`.

Comment: are you getting excel generated??

Comment: My file name is `time_records.xls` .. the excel file gets downloaded as `time_records (1).xls` or (2) or (3) or so on...

Comment: if you remove it every time then only it will be  time_records.xls

Answer (score 0):

you can use php basename() function to get the file names at that specific path and then check if the file you are creating already exists.
if it already exists then delete the old file and create the new file.
https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filesystem_basename.asp

and this should be done before you call header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");